# Eclipse does not show EclipseLink platform in JPA configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, eclipselink, facet

I'm trying to set up JPA facet. All tutorials online state that I should select EclipseLink platform and not Generic. The thing is in my eclipse only Generic appears.
I've installed Eclipse Web tools hoping that it would appear but looks like I need to add EclipseLink into a folder where Eclipse can find it.
My project is a Maven project so I am currently importing EclipseLink via pom.xml.
How do I make EclipseLink platform appear?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UQJKkqqiVDo) video tutorial (it shows how to add it via the "Project Facets" feature).

Comment: I've seen the video and unfortunately that does not solve my problem.
In his case the drop-down list shows EclipseLink version to pick on the "Platform" context. My Eclipse Luna only shows Generic.

Comment: Similar method works for me with Eclipse Mars. I have feature "Dali Java Persistence Tools - EclipseLink JPA Support" installed.

Comment: Just confirmed in Luna -- i.e. works for me (with "Dali Java Persistence Tools - EclipseLink JPA Support" installed and eclipselink 2.5.0-RC1 in pom.xml)

Comment: YES!!! It worked for me too! I have installed a different Web Tools Platform.
Much appreciated!!