# Eclipse: When converting to JPA, I can't select EclipseLink from the Platform dropdown menu

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

This question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32592812/eclipse-does-not-show-eclipselink-platform-in-jpa-configuration), but the answer didn't help. I am trying to convert a Maven project to JPA, but I don't see EclipseLink in the dropdown menu, only Generic 2.2. I already have the correct dependencies in my POM. A screenshot of the dropdown and my POM are below.

[image]

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>consoleshoppinglist</groupId>
  <artifactId>consoleshoppinglist</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.23</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by changing 2.2 next to JPA to 2.1!
[image]