# EclipseLink Platform is missing from JPA Facet Configuration Window

Tags: eclipse, maven, jpa, eclipselink

I am following a book guide to create a database web application using JPA. I am using a Maven project and I am trying to add an Eclipse JPA Facet, but when I go to specify the platform [my only option is Generic 2.2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kM2WB.png). I have set up the dependency in the [pom.xml to include eclipselink 2.5.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGIie.png) and I have installed [Dali Java Persistence Tools - EclipseLink JPA Support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t471S.png), but EclipseLink still does not appear as an available platform.

I have googled this problem and I have only found a couple of people who had [similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32592812/eclipse-does-not-show-eclipselink-platform-in-jpa-configuration). I tried the above solutions which helped them but they have not helped me. Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: 1. EclipseLink 2.5.2 is a JPA 2.1 library (not 2.2;) (if you change your JPA version to 2.1, you should see more options)

Comment: ..perhaps you might want to grab a more up-to-date tutorial!? (eclipselink 2.5.2 is from 2014:)

Comment: Yes! Changing my JPA version to 2.1 lets me see EclipseLink! Thank you so much. And gosh, that is an old version... this was the textbook my course gave me and I figured it was a little out of date, but not that much! Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing my JPA library to 2.1 in the Project Facets screen allowed me to select EclipseLink as a platform. Thanks Xerx593!

Comment: (Hi&) Welcome, bud! ;)